# criação de tabelas para cadastrar questões no postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Estou fazendo um programa onde o usuário pode cadastrar e buscar questões.
Cada questão tem um domínio(ex:direito, psicologia), vários temas, uma dificuldade, o texto da questão e a resposta.
até o momento meu codigo cadastra e busca as questões, mas agora vou implementá-lo a um banco de dados, mas sou muito leigo no assunto e estou tendo problemas para criar as tabelas sempre me deparo com diversos erros e agora não estou conseguindo criar essa sequência de tabelas:
[image: Diagrama simples representando as tabelas]

---

Estou tentando criar com este código:

```
CREATE TABLE tab_dominio (id_dominio SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dominio varchar (50))

CREATE TABLE dificuldade (dificuldade int)

CREATE TABLE tab_questoes (id_questao SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dominio varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY references tab_dominio(dominio), dificuldade FOREIGN KEY references dificuldade(dificuldade), pergunta varchar(250), resposta varchar(250))

CREATE TABLE tab_temas (id_tema SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, dominio varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY references tab_dominio(dominio), tema varchar(50))

CREATE TABLE questaotema (id_questao int FOREIGN KEY references tab_questoes(id_questao), id_tema FOREIGN KEY references tab_temas(tema))
```

Mas estou obtendo o erro:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "FOREIGN" LINE 1: ... SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dominio varchar(50) FOREIGN KE..
```

Se eu apago onde diz que há erro ele continua mostrando mais e mais erros e no fim não consigo criar minha tabela, estou travado nisso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `INTEGER REFERENCES` no lugar de  `FOREIGN KEY references`

Referência -> http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-foreign-key/

Exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE tab_dominio (id_dominio SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dominio varchar (50))


CREATE TABLE dificuldade (id_dificuldade  integer UNIQUE)

CREATE TABLE tab_questoes (
    id_questao SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    id_dominio INTEGER REFERENCES  tab_dominio(id_dominio), 
    dificuldade INTEGER REFERENCES   dificuldade(id_dificuldade), 
    pergunta varchar(250), 
    resposta varchar(250)
);
```

Ou vc pode usar outra forma, onde primeiro define o campo na tabela  **`id_dominio INTEGER`** e depois atribui a ele status de chave estrangeira  **`FOREIGN KEY (id_dominio) REFERENCES tab_dominio (id_dominio),`**

```
CREATE TABLE tab_questoes (
    id_dominio INTEGER,
    id_questao SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    FOREIGN KEY (id_dominio) REFERENCES tab_dominio (id_dominio),
    dificuldade INTEGER REFERENCES   dificuldade(id_dificuldade), 

    pergunta varchar(250), 
    resposta varchar(250)
);
```

Comment: Funcionou, alterei todo o restante dos códigos de acordo com a formatação que você mostrou e criou todas as tabelas tranquilamente, Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode colocar um campo que não identifica univocamente uma linha como chave estrangeira em outra tabela.

Pelo desenho talvez falte o relacionamento entre as tabelas tabela_questoes e Temas.

Substitua `dominio` por `id_dominio`.

```
CREATE TABLE tab_dominio (
    id_dominio SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    dominio varchar (50)
);

CREATE TABLE dificuldade (
    dificuldade int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE tab_questoes (
    id_questao SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    id_dominio int references tab_dominio(id_dominio), 
    dificuldade int references dificuldade(dificuldade), 
    pergunta varchar(250), 
    resposta varchar(250)
);

CREATE TABLE tab_temas (
    id_tema SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    id_dominio int references tab_dominio(id_dominio), 
    tema varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE questaotema (
    id_questao int references tab_questoes(id_questao), 
    id_tema int references tab_temas(id_tema),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_questao, id_tema)
);
```

Entendo a existência da tabela dificuldade unicamente para assegurar consistência dos valores permitidos, que talvez possa ser substituído por uma cláusula CHECK.

Você utiliza a expressão FOREIGN KEY no caso de table_constraint:

```
[ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ] FOREIGN KEY ( column_name [, ... ] ) REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn [, ... ] ) ]
```

No caso da column_constraint use:

```
[ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ] REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn ) ] [ MATCH FULL | MATCH PARTIAL | MATCH SIMPLE ]
[ ON DELETE action ] [ ON UPDATE action ]
```

Comment: realmente esqueci de colocar o relacionamento entre as tabelas tabela_questoes e Temas no desenho, peço desculpas, tentei com as alterações que você falou mas permaneceu apresentando o mesmo erro que coloquei mais acima, ja fiz diversas alterações na ordem da escrita mas sempre aponta erro no primeiro "FOREIGN" que encontra

Comment: Por erro de digitação tinha um nome de campo errado, d_dominio no lugar de id_dominio. Corrigido.